# HiC : Structure within Structure?

Tags: c, compiler-errors, structure

this is my first time using structure within a structure. 
I encounter this error when I compile my program.
error: field 'results' has incomplete type.

The error is referring to this line of code.
-->struct result_t results;

Any help please? :)
Thanks.

```
typedef struct {
char moduleCode[8];
char grade[3];
} result_t;

typedef struct {
char name[31];
struct result_t results;
} student_t;
```

Edit:

I changed my codes:

```
typedef struct {
char moduleCode[8];
char grade[3];
} result_t;

typedef struct {
char name[31];
result_t results;
} student_t;
```

and I got a new compilation error. 
error : subscripted value is neither array nor pointer.

The line of code that triggered that error is as follows. 
printf(" %-7s %-2s %d\n", student.results[i].module_code, student.results[i].grade, student.results[i].mc);

Comment: Original question has been edited. So it is difficult to determine what the problem was, as solved by the accepted answer

Comment: The original question has not been edited, but there is a second part of the question in the comment to my answer. should we edit the original question in order to include also this second part?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Result is not an array. you should either change the structure student with:

```
typedef struct {
    char name[31];
    result_t results[MAX_NUM_RESULTS];
} student_t;
```

Or change the printf to:

```
printf(" %-7s %-2s %d\n", student.results.module_code, student.results.grade, student.results.mc);
```

It depends on how many possible results one student may have.

Comment: Thanks :)
I changed the structure student with typedef struct { char name[31]; result_t results[MAX_NUM_RESULTS]; } student_t; and it worked! Thanks! :)

Comment: @LawrenceWong So after your change, reading the question and the accepted answer literally make no sense together. It is better to leave them in a state that might be useful for others latter.

Answer (score 0):

since you are using typedef use this

```
typedef struct {
char name[31];
result_t results;<---remove struct
} student_t;
```

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your prompt reply. I changed my codes and I got a new compilation error.
error : subscripted value is neither array nor pointer.
The line of code that triggered that error is as follows.                                                              printf("  %-7s %-2s %d\n", student.results[i].module_code,
                student.results[i].grade, student.results[i].mc);